# How to prune Ubuntu to bare essentials

Tags: raspberry-pi, java

I have a Raspberry Pi running a Java application (with Swing/GUI) in a kiosk-like setup.

I want to terminate (or preferably prevent from starting) all unnecessary processes that are not essential for my application to run.

How can I identify the mandatory processes and prevent them from starting?

I attempted to search for this information on Google, but unfortunately, I haven't had any luck so far.

My application includes a GUI, utilizes a mouse and keyboard, doesn't require network access, and needs to interact with specific USB devices.

While I don't necessarily need Ubuntu, I do require a 64-bit OS for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ubuntu is rather bloated. getting it down to a "bare minimum" state is much more complex than choosing a different, more lightweight distro (Debian comes to mind).

Comment: @Panki good point, I will check if something has appeared for Rasberry since I last checked ... when the 64 bit landscape was pretty barren.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the internet does not know what the dependencies are for your software / hardware / use-case.

Only you can find that out.

Running `systemd status` will give you a list of the services currently running. Running `systemd status <servicename>` will tell you where the [unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) is for each service - any 'After' 'Wants', 'Requires' or 'Before' is an explicit dependency. That will give you a starting point for inentifying what you can safely turn off. Note all dependencies may be explicitly flagged in the unit files.

Then it's simply a matter of turning off a service at a time and testing the behaviour. Use `systemctl stop <servicename>` to turn it off, and `systemctl disable <servicename>` to prevent it starting automatically the next time you boot.

Ideally you should be uninstalling redundant components. The dependencies defined in software packages *should* allign to the startup, but that's not always the case.